# Linking option in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, window-resize

I want to update a some expression whenever the window gets resized.
Below is my directive show what i tried.

**SCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("validate", function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.outp = "hello";
});
app.directive("responsive", function($window) {
    return {
        resterict: "AE",
        link: function cLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element);
            scope.widthe = ($window).outerWidth;
            //scope.$watch("widthe",function(newValue, oldValue){
            //scope.chnage = newValue;

            //});

            element.bind("resize", function() {
                console.log("called");
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }

    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="validate" responsive>
        <div style="border:solid;width:500px;height:500px;">
            <div>present width is {{width}}</div>
            <div>{{chnage}}</div>
            <button id="clicks">click me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Using above Code, I'm not able to bind resize event with element.
I want to update the width whenever the window is resized.
Could you help me to find out solution on it with code refactoring suggestions.

Help would appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: just do  window.onresize https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon You're correct, I'd just suggest use `$window` service instead of `window`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.onresize` function inside your directive link, then height changing logic will lie inside that, but in if you want to do it in angular way then you need to use `$window` API of Angular same as that of `window`.

**Directive**

```
app.directive("responsive", function($window) {
    return {
        resterict: "AE",
        link: function cLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element);
            scope.width = ($window).outerWidth;
            //scope.$watch("widthe",function(newValue, oldValue){
               //scope.chnage = newValue;

            //});

            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
                console.log("called");
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks alot!!! it binded the resize function. What can I do to update a expression in my HTML when the window is resized?

Comment: You can do it using `$broadcast` and then `$on` you can listen that event

Comment: @ShahRukhK If my answer does help you then mark it as correct Thanks, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198733/how-to-mark-comment-as-answer